# Change the image of popup when link clicked with FancyBox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have a page with a couple of links (`<a>`) with images inside (`<img>`) in the page. I want that when an image is clicked a two column popup appears showing the image clicked.
My problem is that with the code below only the first image is shown and it doesn't do anything when the second one is clicked.
Any ideas how to resolve it?
Thanks in advance! Guillermo.

**Links html**

```
   <table class="tableHouse">
        <tr align="center" >
            <td>
                <span class="thumbnailTitle">Table</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="thumbnailTitle">Chair</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="spaceUnder">
            <td>
                <div><a id="thumbnailTitleLink" href="#popup_wrapper" name="table"><img id="imgTable" alt="Table" src="images/house/table_thumb.png"/></a></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div><a id="thumbnailTitleLink" href="#popup_wrapper" name="chair"><img id="imgChair" alt="Chair" src="images/house/chair.png"/></a></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Then, when the hyperlink is clicked, I want to show a two columns popup with bullets on the left and the image on the right like this one:

```
<div id="popup_wrapper" class="popup_wrapper">
    <div class="popup_left_box">
        <div id="tablePopupText" class="popupText">
            <span class="popupTitle">Table</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Description 1</li>
                <li>Description 2</li>
                <li>Description 3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="chairPopupText" class="popupText">
            <span class="popupTitle">Chair</span>
            <ul>
                <li>Description 1</li>
                <li>Description 2</li>
                <li>Description 3</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS for the two columns**

```
div.popup_wrapper{
    width: 670px;
}

div.popup_left_box{
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 310px;
}

div.popup_right_box{
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 310px;
}
```

**Finally the js script to make the magic happen**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".popupText").each(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

$(".popupImage").hide();

$("#thumbnailTitleLink").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    var srcImage = "";
    var altImage = "";

    var img = $(this).find("img"), 
    len = img.length; // check if they exist
    if( len > 0 ){
        // images found, get id
        altImage = img.first().attr("alt");
        srcImage = img.first().attr("src");
    }

    $(this).fancybox({
        hideOnContentClick : false,
        autoScale: false,
        transitionIn : "elastic",
        transitionOut: 'elastic',
        easingIn : 'easeOutCirc',
        overlayColor : "#1e72b1",
        overlayOpacity : .4,
        opacity: false,
        speedIn : 950,
        titleShow: false,
        scrolling: "no",
        orig: img,
        onComplete : function() {
            $(".popupText").each(function() {
                $(this).hide();
            });
            $(".popupImage").show();

            $('#popup_wrapper').show();

            $('#imgPopup').alt = altImage;
            $('#imgPopup').src = srcImage;
            $('#' + name + 'PopupText').show();
        },
        openEffect  : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic',
        helpers : {
            title : {
                type : 'inside'
            }
        }
    });
} );

});
```

Comment: Finally, I've answered my own question [here][1]

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225604/fancybox-as-popup-and-image-moving-effect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, there were a couple of errors.
First of all, it's not id="thumbnailTitleLink" it's class="thumbnailTitleLink".

Then I did a couple of changes that can be seen in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13225604/fancybox-as-popup-and-image-moving-effect)